# Output API with pagination in FullCalendar Events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fullcalendar

I have a big api and it is divided into pages, 20 events per page, switching pages using a get request, for example: "?page=1"

And I need to display this api on the calendar, I use it for this FullCalendar

Is it possible somehow in this calendar to display such api paginally, if so, then please tell me

Comment: the first thing that i can think of is to have the [events as a function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function) and then in this function you loop as long as there are more pages and append the result to an array before returning it

Comment: fullCalendar expects the events returned to be relevant to the time period being displayed on the calendar (e.g. one month, or one week, or whatever). Does this API have the ability to do that instead? A "page" doesn't really relate to a time period, I expect. If not, then of course you can write some code to call the relevant pages of the API, combine the lists together and then pass it to fullCalendar as a single list. Beware of loading too many events at once though, especially if they're not relevant. Perhaps you should add your own date-range filtering, too.

Comment: @ADyson yes, I think I’ll filter by date range, thanks!